# Как обучить простую нейронную сеть

Tags: c++, нейронные-сети

Пытаюсь создать нейронную сеть xor с backpropagation. Все формулы подобрал правильно, но после обучения ответ при любом входе равен ~0.5. Скорее всего, ошибка здесь, хотя везде где я читал описывается такой способ:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    train(1, 1, 0.1, net); // train(input1, input2, ожидаемый результат, ссылка на сеть)
    train(1, 0, 0.9, net);
    train(0, 1, 0.9, net);
    train(0, 0, 0.1, net);
}
```

Если разобраться, то понятно почему это происходит: при первом выполнении функции train с ожидаемым результатом 0.1 веса смещаются в одну сторону, а при ожидаемом 0.9 - в другую, и в результате получается так, что нейросеть выдает среднее значение от ответов из тренировочного сета при любом входе.
Полный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

const double E = 0.7; // learning speed
const double A = 0.3; // moment

using namespace std;

double sigmoid(double x)
{
    return 1/(1 + pow(2.7,-x));
}
double derSigm(double x)
{
    return sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x));
}

class synapse
{
public:
    double weight;
    double grad;
    double deltaW;
    double prevDeltaW = 0;

    synapse(double weight)
    {
        this->weight = weight;
    }

    void countDeltaW(double deltaB, double outA)
    {
        grad = deltaB*outA;
        deltaW = E*grad + A*prevDeltaW;
        prevDeltaW = deltaW;
        weight += deltaW;
    }
};

class neuron
{
public:
    vector<synapse> oSynapse; // Исходящие из одного нейрона синапсы
    double input = 0;
    double output = 1;
    double delta;

    neuron(int size)
    {
        double randWeight = (rand() % 2000) - 1000;
        randWeight = randWeight/1000;
        oSynapse.resize(size, randWeight);
    }
    void transferRes(vector<neuron> &nextLayer)
    {
        output = sigmoid(this->input);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < oSynapse.size(); i++){
            nextLayer[i].input += output*oSynapse[i].weight;
        }
    }
    void lastLayerRes()
    {
        output = sigmoid(this->input);
    }
    double countDelta(double expected) // для последнего слоя
    {
        this->delta = (expected - output)*derSigm(input);
        return this->delta;
    }
    double countDelta(vector<neuron> &nextLayer)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < oSynapse.size(); i++){
            sum += oSynapse[i].weight*nextLayer[i].delta;
        }
        delta = derSigm(input)*sum;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < oSynapse.size(); i++){
            oSynapse[i].countDeltaW(nextLayer[i].delta, this->output);
        }

        return delta;
    }
};

void countResult(vector<vector<neuron> > &net)
{
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < (net.size()-1); x++){
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < net[x].size(); y++){
            net[x][y].transferRes(net[x+1]);
        }
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < net.back().size(); i++){
        net.back()[i].lastLayerRes();
    }
}
void updateNet(vector<vector<neuron> > &net) // обновляет input и output во всех нейронах
{
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < net.size(); x++){
        for(unsigned int y = 0; y < net[x].size(); y++){
            net[x][y].input = 0;
            net[x][y].output = 0;
        }
    }
}

void train(int input1, int input2, double expected, vector<vector<neuron> > &net)
{
    net[0][0].input = input1;
    net[0][1].input = input2;
    countResult(net);

    net.back()[0].countDelta(expected);
    for (int x = net.size() - 2; x >= 0; x--){
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < net[x].size(); y++){
            net[x][y].countDelta(net[x+1]);
        }
    }

    updateNet(net);
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<neuron> > net(3);
    net[0].resize(2, 3); // второй параметр - количество синапсов от нейрона == нейронов в след. слое
    net[1].resize(3, 1);
    net[2].resize(1, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        train(0.9, 0.9, 0.1, net);
        train(0.9, 0.1, 0.9, net);
        train(0.1, 0.9, 0.9, net);
        train(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, net);
    }


    net[0][0].input = 0.1;
    net[0][1].input = 0.9;
    countResult(net);
    cout << net[2][0].output;


    return 0;
}
```

Искал везде где мог, но других вариантов не нашел. Наверное неправильно понял, но как тогда правильно?

Comment: На будущее, код [лучше вставлять в сам вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Вот [хороший урок для чайника](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HA-F6cZPvrg) с формулами, как учить.

Comment: У вас начальные веса в каждом слое случайные, но одинаковые

Comment: Да, веса одинаковые были. Уже исправил, но проблема осталась